Dead key affects two next key presses in Ubuntu24.04
I am migrating from Ubuntu-MATE 22.04, so probably it's an issue of GNOME or ibus, or I don't know of what is used here, especially on Wayland. But I didn't find a clue until now.
So I am using Latvian keyboard layout, using 'Latvian (apostrophe)' option. I have now discovered that a single dead key (apostrophe) press actually always affects not just the next, but two next key presses, so instead of 'ļauj' I am getting 'ļāuj'. This is also not connected with delay between the key presses: I can wait as long as I want, the next letter still will be affected. It looks like a bug to me, but I am not sure. I look forward to Your help!
System is freshly installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (with GNOME v. 46 on Wayland). Kernel Linux 6.8.0-35-generic. HP 250 G7 Notebook.

I had the same issue on vanilla Ubuntu 24.04, and the workaround proposed in this bug report worked for me. Try adding the following lines to ~/.profile, then log out and log back in, or reboot:
# extra apostrophe/accent character bug workaround
# https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/2040450
INPUT_METHOD=ibus
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus


Thank You very much, it worked!  I suspected this is somehow connected with ibus of XIM of whatever, because there is now no switch for input method neither in GNOME Settings, nor in Tweaks (or I could not find it).
